# Cross compilation library linking

Tags: c, compilation

If we cross compile for arm platform, should we link the library files which compatible for the platform or we can use host compatible library files?

Like the below example, if we do cross compilation for arm platform, then the curl library we are linking also should be the cross compiled one or our host compatible libraries?

arm-v5te-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o main main.c -L/usr/local/curl

Comment: You must always use the target platform libraries and never the host libraries.

Comment: @kaylum, thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... then the curl library we are linking also should be the cross compiled one ... ?

Yes. It should be the cross compiled one, not the host one.